# The Einstein-Hilbert Action On-Shell

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, action

If one consider the Maxwell action as 
$$S=-\int \mathrm{d^{4}}x\! \ \frac{1}{4}F_{ab}F^{ab} \,$$
one find the usual Maxwell equation
$$\partial_{a}F^{ab}=0$$
Then one can simply arrive the following the Maxwell **on-shell** action
$$-\int \mathrm{d^{4}}x\! \ \frac{1}{2}\partial_{a}(A_{b}F^{ab}) \,$$

Now my question is for Einstein Hilbert action. What is the expression of **on-shell** Einstein Hilbert action
$$S=\int \mathrm{d^{4}}x\! \ R \,$$
I know how to find Einstein equation from variational principle, which is given as 
$$R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}R=0$$

How to write **on-shell** Einstein Hilbert action with above equation?

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): There are several notions of on-shell actions. Consider including a definition or reference for clarity.

Comment: By on-shell action, I mean the action - the equation of motion. For clarity I have included the example with Maxwell action.

Comment: I want a similar form for On-shell Einstein Hilbert action  just like the-shell Maxwell action$$-\int \mathrm{d^{4}}x\! \ \frac{1}{2}\partial_{a}(A_{b}F^{ab}) \,$$

Answer (score 1):

The action you're considering yields Einstein's equations *in vacuum*, so $R=0$ (this follows immediately from contracting Einstein's equations). Therefore the action vanishes on shell.

Comment: That is true. But my question is more general. Suppose one consider Einstein-Hilbert-Maxwell action. Then there will be two equations of motion, one for metric and one for gauge field. The what would be the form of on-shell action then?

Comment: Then the equations of motion will be coupled: due to the Maxwell term it's not a vacuum solution anymore. In this case the EE become $R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=\kappa T_{\mu\nu}$ and the Maxwell equations become $D_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}=0$. If for example we consider only electric fields in four dimensions, a solution is given by the Reissner Nordstrom metric together with $A_0=-Q/r+\Phi$, where $Q$ is the black hole charge and $\Phi$ is constant. As it turns out, the EM tensor is traceless in this specific case so that $R=0$ again.

Comment: In fact a more general result holds: the EM tensor for Maxwell fields is $T_{\mu\nu}=F_{\mu\rho}F_{\nu}^{\rho}-\frac{1}{4}F_{\rho\sigma}F^{\rho\sigma}$, so clearly $T_{\mu}^{\mu}=0$ in four dimensions. Hence $R=0$ for the Einstein-Hilbert-Maxwell action (but only in 4 dimensions!), so that you're only left with the on-shell Maxwell part.